# How to pass "By" and String for it in Selenium test method?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So I want to pass two things for my methods, String - that would be a property name and By - that would allow to chose by what criteria element should be searched. Simple example:

```
public static WebElement getElement(By by) {
    return driver.findElement(by);
}
```

But that would force me to use it that way:

```
element = getElement(By.className(properties.getProperty("class")));
```

While I would like to use it like this:

```
element = getElement(By.className, "class");
```

How can I do this? I thought that simple code like this would work, but unfortunately it returns error

> "by(String) is undefined"

```
public static WebElement getElement(By by, String string) {
    return driver.findElement(by(properties.getProperty(string));
}
```

EDIT:
I decided to settle on using:

```
public static String useProperty(String propertyName) {
    return properties.getProperty(propertyName);
}
```

Not exactly how I wanted to handle it, but it does allow to simplify and improve readability of code.

Answer (score 6):

This isn't possible, [By.className()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html#className-java.lang.String-) is a method which receives a `String` parameter. This `String` is used to initialize the inner class [By.ByClassName](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.ByClassName.html) and this is the returned `By`.

You could build `switch case` to handle this, something like

```
public static WebElement getElement(String string) {
    By by = null;
    String locator = properties.getProperty(string);

    switch (string) {
        case "class":
            by = By.className(locator);
            break;
        case "id":
            by = By.id(locator);
            break;
    }

    return driver.findElement(by);
}
```

Comment: @RatmirAsanov Thanks. I saw the edit, the `switch` need to be on the `string`, not the `locator`.

Comment: Yes, sorry, this is my fault.

Comment: Thanks, it is a solution, but I guess it's not very optimal way to handle it. I think I will settle on making additional method to shorten it.

Answer (score 0):

The "By" can not be represented as String. There is another example:

```
public void Test_xy() throws InterruptedException {     

        String[] by = {"id", "xpath"};
        String[] property_name = {"value", "title"};

        driver.get("https://www.example.com");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        WebElement more_info = getElement(by[1], "/html/body/div/p[2]/a");
        String element_title = getProperty(more_info, property_name[1]);

    }

    public WebElement getElement(String by, String by_value) {
        if (by == "id") {WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id(by_value));return element;}
        else if (by == "xpath") {WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(by_value));return element;}
        // else if (by == different locator) ...
        else {return null;}
    }

    public String getProperty(WebElement element, String chosen_property) {
        return element.getAttribute(chosen_property);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be with generics:

```
private <T extends By> WebElement getElement(Class<T> byType, String prop) {

    if (byType.equals(ByClassName.class))
        return getDriver().findElement(By.className(prop));
    else if (byType.equals(ByCssSelector.class))
        return getDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector(prop));
    else if (byType.equals(ById.class))
        return getDriver().findElement(By.id(prop));
    else if (byType.equals(ByLinkText.class))
        return getDriver().findElement(By.linkText(prop));
    else if (byType.equals(ByName.class))
        return getDriver().findElement(By.name(prop));
    else if (byType.equals(ByPartialLinkText.class))
        return getDriver().findElement(By.partialLinkText(prop));
    else if (byType.equals(ByTagName.class))
        return getDriver().findElement(By.tagName(prop));
    else if (byType.equals(ByXPath.class))
        return getDriver().findElement(By.xpath(prop));
    else
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

And you would use it like:

```
@Test
public void myWebElementTest() {
    WebElement div1 = getElement(By.ByName.class, "div1");
    WebElement id1 = getElement(By.ById.class, "id1");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple Implementation :

```
public WebElement getLocator(String locatorType, String locatorValue ){

    switch(locatorType.toUpperCase()) {
    case "ID":
        return driver.findElement(By.id(locatorValue ));
    case "CSSSELECTOR":
        return driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(locatorValue));
    case "XPATH":
        return driver.findElement(By.xpath(locatorValue));
    case "NAME":
        return driver.findElement(By.name(locatorValue));
    case "LINKTEXT":
        return driver.findElement(By.linkText(locatorValue));
    case "PARTIALLINKTEXT":
        return driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText(locatorValue);
    case "TAGNAME":
        return driver.findElement(By.tagName(locatorValue));
    case "CLASSNAME":
        return driver.findElement(By.className(locatorValue));
    default:
        LOGGER.info("Incorrect locator or Type" +  locatorType);
    }
}
```